# Heartbeat method in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a Meteor application that, for every second while the user is holding a button, decrements a value on a post by 1. There are many many buttons, and each should only affect itself.

If one person is holding the button, it will go down by a rate of one per second. If two people (on different clients) then by two per second.

The exact moment at which it is updated in the database is unnecessary, only that the client should see the counter decrement by a variable amount each second.

So to trigger the method I used the following

```
Template.button.onRendered(function() {
  var data = this.data;

  Meteor.setInterval(function() {
    if(isClicked) {
      Meteor.call('heartbeat', data);
    }
  }, 1000);
});
```

which calls a client/server method

```
'heartbeat': function(button) {
  Buttons.update({_id: button._id}, {$inc: {life: -1}});

  if(button.life <= 1) {
    console.log('REMOVE DEAD BUTTONS');
    Buttons.remove({life: {$lte: 0}});
  }
}
```

And causes weird activity when latency comes into play. When I click on a button, its life goes down predictably at 1hz on my client. On a different client, its life might stand still for several seconds, and then decrement in chunks of 2 to 4 until it catches up. It is supposed to just jump to the new value as soon as it hears from the server that it's been updated, rather than ramping down.

But since there is no code to make it ramp, I am led to believe that there is something more fundamentally wrong in play. There are three states a button goes through:

```
Client A decrements value -> Server decrements value -> Client B reads value
```

The problem seems to between Client A and the server, so perhaps setting an interval to call a method every second is the bottleneck here that I need to fix, but I'm not sure of any elegant solutions. If instead of sending each update, I adopted a dead reckoning approach and send the start and ends and had the server interpolate on each second in between, that might alleviate some issues, but I don't know if I'm going to run into more unexpected issues along that line.

Is there a significantly better way of decrementing a counter on the second every second for every client reactively?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternate approach:

1. When the user *presses* the button (catch this in a template event handler), make a `Meteor.call()` to the server and have the server decrement every second.
2. When the user *releases* the button, make another `Meteor.call()` to cancel the decrementing. You'll need to keep a handle to the `setInterval` so you can cancel it.

This way you'll remove the client->server lag for doing the updates.